# Is it possible to get notified only once if several model attributes change simultaniously?

Tags: javascript, marionette

I want to have a Marionette ItemView (or LayoutView), which rerenders when its model changes. It is actually pretty easy to implement:

```js
modelEvents: {
  'change': 'render'
}
```

However, not every view displays every attribute of the model. So I had an idea to lessen the number of rerenders by listening to only those events, that change some of the attributes. If only one attribute is required by the view, the situation is also easy:

```js
modelEvents: {
  'change:attribute': 'render'
}
```

However, it is more complicated, if several attribute changes need to be listened to. Both

```js
modelEvents: {
  'change:attribute1': 'render',
  'change:attribute2': 'render'
}
```

and

```js
modelEvents: {
  'change:attribute1 change:attribute2': 'render'
}
```

would rerender the view twice if both attribute1 and attribute2 are changed in one event. Is there any simple syntax to be notified only once in such an occasion? I know, I can do this:

```js
modelEvents: {
  'change': 'checkIfRenderNeeded'
},
checkIfRenderNeeded: function(event) {
  if (('attribute1' in event.changed) || ('attribute2' in event.changed)) {
    this.render();
  }
}
```

But is there some more elegant solution? Maybe some special syntax to include this behaviour in modelEvents property without having to program a change checker on general change event listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same solution as Paul Rowe, but in the context of Marionette:

you can use  Underscore's [_.debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function to wrap your `render` function:

```
var lazyRender = _.debounce(render, 50)
```

and

```
modelEvents: {
  'change:attribute1 change:attribute2': 'lazyRender'
}
```

Then, if both `attribute1` and `attribute2` change, even several times, within a 50 milliseconds timespan, `lazyRender` will be called several times but the `render` function will only be called once.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. It is not the answer, I expected, but good to know such possibility. The problem with this solution might be picking the right interval of time. On one side, two events might be too spread out (e.g. slow computer) so the render would still fire twice. On the other hand, two separate events might be the reason for the two changes and the chosen interval might be too large. Or maybe I shouldn't worry about that too much...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with marionette, but I'll pull a page from my own experience.

Set up a function that serves as a front to render. All attempts to render go through this function. This function manages a timer which, when complete, fires the render function. Whenever the function is called, it clears the timer so there are no queued requests to render. It then resets the timer.